# Identify Architectural Patterns by Java Code

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, identify

How can I identify architectural patterns by looking at the javadoc.
I have downloaded the Source for Pokerapp v.100 (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pokerapp/files/PokerApp%20v1.00/Source%20Code/PokerApp_v1.00-src.tar.gz/download)

and I would like to identify the used patterns for training purposes.
I have just started to work with patterns and I thought that it would be a lot easier.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I recommend the book 'Design Patterns Explained', which explains most of the GoF patterns. I think that's more useful than looking at this application. Also, the book Domain Driven Design by Eric Evans describes numerous patterns, some on a higher level. Also 'must read'.

Answer (score 1):

From just looking at the javadoc this is not possible (except for the cases where javadoc actually mentions the patterns).

But you have the source code ... look at classes that reference each other, understand what they are doing, cross check with the patterns. Done. Of course you can always look for names of patterns or roles of patterns in the names of classes ("Factory" is a common part in class names)

Easy in theory hard and tedious work when you are new to patterns. And possibly not that good a training ...